# HTML5 - Switching Images using dropdown menus or radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

This is probably a stupid & obvious question, but does anyone know how to change an image being displayed in a canvas using dropdown menus or radio buttons?

So if I had a red cloudy image and I wanted to replace it with, say, a green cloudy image, using the dropdowns/radios, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onChange-Event of the dropDown menu or radiobutton and call a javascript function, passing to it the name of the image.

```
<input type="radio" name="cloud" value="red" onChange="javascript:imgChange('red.gif')"> Red cloud<br>
<input type="radio" name="cloud" value="blue" onChange="javascript:imgChange('blue.gif')"> Blue cloud<br>
<input type="radio" name="cloud" value="green" onChange="javascript:imgChange('green.gif')"> green cloud
```

Using javascript you can now build a function to change the image.

```
function imgChange(var img){
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image;
    // set your image according to the parameter
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
```

Comment: Well, uh, I'm an epic Javascript noob, and I can't work out how to do this :C I've set up the radio tables, but getting them to change the image doesn't work...

Comment: In fact, the radio tables don't work properly too - I can select mutiple buttons

Comment: make sure that they all have the same name. this will put them in the same group and you should be able to select only one. As for the JS, you can use my function and replace the comment with something from here: [link](http://www.jefclaes.be/2010/12/html5-drawing-images-to-canvas-gotcha.html)

Comment: Okay, well, I've got the radios working and I've put the code in, but how do I get the code to detect which button is presses :S

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample code for me to look at please? Because at the moment I'm just running around with my hair on fire

Comment: Sorry, haven't check in again until now, due to work. Could you please post your result here for future users? Also: depending on what radio button you select, the function gets called with a different parameter. this is how it should work. See, my source

Comment: This is what I used: <br />`function imgChange(imgURL){
 var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = imgURL;
 img.onload = function(){
 ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
 }
}` and <br /> `<input type="radio" name="blank" value="1" onChange="javascript:imgChange('http://i.imgur.com/eWRv9.png')"> <img src="N7wLU.png" alt="Normal" height="20" width="20"> B` Where "N7wLU.png" is the URL of the image you want to display